# $x\in \overline A \iff$ - how to derive definition of closure

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X$ be a metric space with a metric $d$.

Why does $x\in \overline A \iff \forall \epsilon>0, A\cap V_{\epsilon} (x) \neq \emptyset \tag{1}$

?

There are many posts that take it as no-need-to-be-proven result, however I haven't found a proof, which is probably quite basic.

I know the definition of a limit point, but it is difficult for me to derive $(1)$ from it.

My definition of the closure is $\overline A = A \cup A'$ where $A'$ are the limit points of $A$.

A limit point of $A$ is a point $p$ such as for every neighborhood $V$ of $p$ there exists a point $x\in A$ such as $x\neq p$ and $x\in V$.

A neighborhood of $x$ is the set of $y$ such as $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ where $\epsilon \in \mathbb R^{+*}$.

PS: $V_{\epsilon} (x) $ is the set of $y$ such as $d(x,y)< \epsilon$.

Comment: It matters how you define "closed". There are a few ways to define this in $\Bbb R$ and they're all equivalent, but what a proof looks like will change

Comment: A set $E$ is closed if $E'\subseteq E$

Comment: ... and what is $E'$?

Comment: You tag this "general topology", but the definition you give only holds in a very limited type of metric spaces. It isn't even sensible in $\mathbb{R}^2$...

Comment: $x\in E' \iff \forall \epsilon, V_{\epsilon} \cap E\backslash \{x\} \neq \emptyset$ where $V_{\epsilon}$ is an open ball centered around $x$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, sorry. Post edited

Comment: $V_\epsilon(x)$ is not "**a** neighborhood of $x$", It is the set of all $y$ such that $d(x,y)\lt\epsilon$, where $d$ is the metric in question. You need to be precise, explicit, and accurate, especially when struggling with basic definitions.

Comment: And how do you define the closure of a set? The smallest closed set that contains $A$, or some other definition?

Comment: The statement $A\setminus\{x\}=A$ is true if and only if $x\notin A$. It has nothing to do with metrics, closures, or limit points.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin the closure of a set in my book is defined as the union of the set with its derived set.

Comment: Please put all the relevant information in the post, not buried in the comments. Note that there are **multiple** ways of defining all of these concepts, and proving something about them depends precisely on which definitions you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the definitions you are say you are using, once we dig through the comments (please put them in the post, this time and next!)

1. For $\epsilon\gt0$ and a point $x$, $V_{\epsilon}(x) = \{y\mid d(x,y)\lt \epsilon\}$.
2. For a set $A$, the derived set of $A$ is $$A'=\bigl\{x\;\bigm|\; \forall\epsilon\gt0\  \bigl( (V_{\epsilon}(x)\cap A)\setminus\{x\}\neq\varnothing\bigr)\bigr\}.$$
3. For a set $A$, the closure of $A$ is defined to be $\overline{A}=A\cup A'$.

For simplicity, let
$$F=\{x\mid \forall\epsilon\gt0 \ (V_{\epsilon}(x)\cap A\neq\varnothing)\}.$$
We want to prove that $F=\overline{A}$.

To prove that $\overline{A}\subseteq F$, note that if $x\in A'$, then by definition we have that for all $\epsilon\gt0$, $V_{\epsilon}(x)\cap A\neq\varnothing$, so $x\in F$. Thus, $A'\subseteq F$. And if $x\in A$, then for all $\epsilon\gt 0$, $x\in V_{\epsilon}(x)\cap A$, so $x\in F$. Thus, $A\subseteq F$ also holds. Thus, we have
$$\overline{A} = A\cup A'\subseteq F.$$

Conversely, let $x\in F$; to prove that $x\in\overline{A}$, we need to show that $x\in A$ or that $x\in A'$. If $x\in A$, then we are done. So assume that $x\in F$ and $x\notin A$. Let $\epsilon\gt 0$. We want to show that $(V_{\epsilon}(x)\cap A)\setminus\{x\}\neq\varnothing$.

Because $x\in F$, we know that $V_{\epsilon}(x)\cap A\neq\varnothing$. And because we are assuming that $x\notin A$, then it follows that $x\notin V_{\epsilon}(x)\cap A$. Thus, $(V_{\epsilon}(x)\cap A)\setminus\{x\} = V_{\epsilon}(x)\cap A \neq\varnothing$. We have thus shown that the intersection of $V_{\epsilon}(x)$ with $A$ contains points other than $x$. As this holds for every $\epsilon\gt 0$, it follows that $x\in A'$.

Thus, we have shown that if $x\in F$, then either $x\in A$ or else $x\in A'$. Thus, $F\subseteq A\cup A'= \overline{A}$.

This proves that $F=\overline{A}$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that with the limit definition you  mean that $\overline A$ is the collection of points $a$ such that a path $\{x_i\}_{i = 1}^\infty \subseteq A$ exists that converges to $a$.

The proof is actually quite easy.

1. if $a \in \overline A$, then such a path exists for $a$, then by limit definition, for all $\epsilon > 0$ we can find a point $x_i$ such that $d(a, x_i) < \epsilon$, hence the $V_\epsilon(a)$ has overlap with $A$
2. if every $V_\epsilon(a)$ has overlap with $A$, we can find points $x_i \in V_\frac{1}{i}(a) \cap A$. Now $d(x_i, a) < 1/i$, so $\{x_i\}_{i = 1}^\infty$ converges to $a$, and for all $x_i \in A$. Therefore $a \in \overline A$.

I hope this gives you an idea on why these definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Hi, I didn't know about paths but I will try to check that up on the internet.